# Convert byteArray from fileInputStream

Tags: java, spring, performance, java-8, fileinputstream

I wanna read huge file(more then GB) and convert that as byte array in order to store the file dB.

The problem i am facing is when i convert file to byte array or reading the file i am getting Java heap memory run-time exception

I want to know what is the best way to read file and convert to byte array without being using more memory

I have googled i found that IOUtils provide better performance but i tried that it dint help me. I using java 8

```
private void readFile() throws IOException {

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\test.mp4")
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileInputStream);
            Base64 codec = new Base64();
            byte[] decoded = codec.encode(bytes);

                                            fileInputStream.close();
}
```

Can you please help to convert that file to byte array with best approach?

Comment: If you want to store the File bytes into a DB column as bytes, why do you encode them in Base64()? Do I miss something here?

Comment: @IoannisBarakos  i wanna do that . i am getting heap out memory error in            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileInputStream);

Comment: You get OOM errors as you read the whole file in memory (codec.encode(bytes)). You should not do that. Your DB table should have a BLOB column for storing the file binary data. You first insert an empty blob and then you should get the Stream to this empty blob and start coping bytes from your FileInputStream to the Blobs OutputStream. You can read: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/oralob.htm#i1058066

Answer (score 0):

When you are saying that you want to write to db, avoid reading into an array in memory.
Straight update to db using setCharacterStream.

```
Connection conn = //... initialize connection
PreparedStmt stmt = null;
try {
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(this.insertQuerySql);
    stmt.setLong(1, varLong); 
    stmt.setString(2, varString);
    stmt.setString(3, varString2);
    File file = new File(filePathToVeryLargeFileInGBs);
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    pstmt.setCharacterStream(4, fileReader, Files.size(Paths.get(filePathToVeryLargeFileInGBs);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e);
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (stmt != null ) { 
        stmt.close();
    }   
    if (conn != null ) { 
        try {
            conn.close();
        }   
        catch(Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }   
}
```

If you must read it into a byte[]
Then the better option is to use:

```
byte[] bArr = ByteBuffer.wrap(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(filePathToVeryLargeFileInGBs)));
```